# webView, viewport, how hide scrollbar which shows when scrolling?

Tags: css, webview, css-selectors, scrollbar, viewport

I am making webView application using sass, java gwt and i have problem with scrollbar. When scrolling down scrollbar shows, but I want to it make it invisible.
Selectors like:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
display: none; }
```

doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

To hide scrollbar use `overflow: hidden`

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: `overflow: visible` won't hide a scrollbar ;)